# Read CSV group by 1 column and apply sum, without pandas

Tags: python, csv, group-by

As I wrote in the title I would like to read a CSV, do on this same CSV a group by column, apply sum, after replace the old CSV with the new values using as least libraries as possible (and avoid pandas). I have come this far:

```
index = {}
with open('event.csv') as f:
    cr = reader(f)
    for row in cr:
        index.setdefault(row[0], []).append(int(row[1]))
f.close()

with open('event.csv', 'w', newline='\n') as csv_file:
    writer = writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in index.items():
        writer.writerow([key, value[0]])
csv_file.close()
```

But in this way I can make the average…and also I have to open the file twice, which doesn't seem smart to me. Here is a CSV similar to `event.csv`:

```
work1,100
work2,200
work3,200
work1,50
work3,20
```

Desired output:

```
work1,150
work2,200
work3,220
```

Comment: You're _so_ close! After you've read your csv file, `index` is now a dictionary. The first column of your csv give the keys of this dictionary. The value for each key is a list of integers coming from the second column of the csv where the first column is that key. Now you just need to sum these lists and write the sum to your new csv. Right now, you write the first value of the list to your csv in this line: `writer.writerow([key, value[0]])`. Opening the file once to read and once to write isn't a problem.

Comment: referring to 'Opening the file once to read and once to write isn't a problem.' can you explain me better?

Comment: you said _"I have to open the file twice, which doesn't seem smart to me"_, but there's no reason you shouldn't open the file twice.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but my question is, if I were to use this script 100 times in a minute instead, would I have to open the file 200 times? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: You could open it in `rw` mode and then `.seek(0)` to the start of the file before you write to it. However, opening the file should take an insignificant amount of time compared to writing to it and I don't think you will see significant performance benefits if you do this. You can give it a shot though - check out `timeit` to find the run time of snippets of code.

Comment: ty very much, I really appreciated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually *very* close. Just sum the values read while rewriting the file. Note that when using `with` on a file, you don't have to explicitly close them, it does it for you automatically. Also note that CSV files should be opened with `newline=''`—for reading and writing—as per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader).

```
import csv


index = {}

with open('event.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
    cr = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in cr:
        index.setdefault(row[0], []).append(int(row[1]))

with open('event2.csv', 'w', newline='\n') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, values in index.items():
        value = sum(values)
        writer.writerow([key, value])

print('-fini-')
```

The above could be written a little more concisely by eliminating some temporary variables and using a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
import csv


index = {}

with open('event.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
    for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
        index.setdefault(row[0], []).append(int(row[1]))

with open('event2.csv', 'w', newline='\n') as csv_file:
    csv.writer(csv_file).writerows([key, sum(values)] for key, values in index.items())

print('-fini-')
```

Comment: ty very much, in my opinion the best solution with just one lib. Clear and simple. Well done

Comment: Thanks, that's good to hear. Though arguably less readable—so maybe not as clear—I've added an optimized version to my answer for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to think of it.

Instead of storing arrays of ints during reading and then "compressing" them into the desired value during writing, show up-front that you're summing something during the read:

```py
import csv

from collections import defaultdict

summed_work = defaultdict(int)

with open('event_input.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        work_id = row[0]
        work_value = int(row[1])
        summed_work[work_id] += work_value

with open('event_processed.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for work_id, summed_value in summed_work.items():
        writer.writerow([work_id, summed_value])
```

This is functionally equivalent to what you were aiming for and what **martineau** helped you with, but, I argue, shows you and your reader sooner and more clearly what the intent is.

It technically uses one more library, **defaultdict**, but that's a standard library, and I'm not sure what value you're placing on the number of libraries being used.

**EDIT**

Oh, I just remembered there's the **Counter** class from collections, too.  Might be even clearer:

`summed_work = Counter()`

and everything else is the same.

Comment: thank you so much for your solution. i need to study the collections better, as they can be helpful

Comment: @mat, you're very welcome. I just remembered the **Counter** class... I'm still coming to terms with collections myself :) For the longest time I thought "it's not Pythonic" or some other dogmatic rationale I came up with, but they're there and helpful. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Another simplification of solutions already shown, without additional libraries:

```py
import csv

index = {}

with open('event.csv', newline='') as f:
    cr = csv.reader(f)
    for item,value in cr:
        index[item] = index.get(item, 0) + int(value)  # sum as you go

with open('event2.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(index.items())  # write all the items in one shot

print('-fini-')
```

Comment: I was undecided if this was the best answer. sorry I can not select 2. nice work congratulations and thanks

Answer (score 1):

With an additional library - `convtools`, which provides a lot of functionality not to write a lot of code by hand every time.

```py
from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table


rows = Table.from_csv("event.csv", header=False).into_iter_rows(list)
converter = (
    c.group_by(c.item(0))
    .aggregate(
        (
            c.item(0),
            c.ReduceFuncs.Sum(c.item(1).as_type(int)),
        )
    )
    .gen_converter()
)
processed_rows = converter(rows)
Table.from_rows(processed_rows, header=False).into_csv(
    "event2.csv", include_header=False
)
```

Comment: convtools seems a nice lib! I will explore that. Ty very much.

Comment: Thank you! Should you have any questions, ask here, submit issues or ping on twitter :) Hope you'll enjoy it!